# Set maximum row height in generated excel document

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application users can get excel report. The problem is : when one of the cells in row contains long text, so all row is grow, and excel report looks bad. I need to set maximum row height for all rows in my excel document.

```
 public bool UseOldFormat { get; set; }

 public ExcelFile GetExcelFile()
        {
            var excel = new ExcelFile();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceFileName))
            {
                if (SourceFileName.EndsWith("xls"))
                {
                    excel.LoadXls(SourceFileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    excel.LoadXlsx(SourceFileName, XlsxOptions.PreserveMakeCopy);
                }
            }

            return excel;
        }

public void GenerateReport(string fileName)
        {
            ExcelFile excel = GetExcelFile();

            InsertDataInExcel(excel);

            if (UseOldFormat)
            {
                excel.SaveXls(fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                excel.SaveXlsx(fileName);
            }
        }
```

Can't find in excel options this function. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the range of columns and then can adjust width,height of them as below :

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange setColumnRowRange;
    private void SetColumnAndRowSizes()
    {
        setColumnRowRange = this.Controls.AddNamedRange(
            this.Range["C3", "E6"], "setColumnRowRange");
        this.setColumnRowRange.ColumnWidth = 20;
        this.setColumnRowRange.RowHeight = 25;
        setColumnRowRange.Select();
    }
```

visit :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.rowheight.aspx

Comment: when i create excel file: var excel = new ExcelFile(), the excel not have NamedRange property

Comment: visit this : http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Spreadsheet/Help/html/M_GemBox_Spreadsheet_NamedRangeCollection_Add.htm

Comment: Thanks. Found it: sheet.Columns[i].Width = x, sheet.Rows[j].Height = y;

Answer (score 0):

This macro does the trick if you just have a file with some too high rows:
 
(up to you, Oleg, how to integrate it in a document creation tool, in case)

```
Sub MaxRowHeight()
    Dim Re As Long
    Re = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    For i = 1 To Re
        If Rows(i).Height > 43.2 Then Rows(i).RowHeight = 43.2
    Next i
End Sub
```

Credits go to this article and the discussion there: 
 http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010381_Adjusting_to_a_Maximum_Row_Height.html